# secure random numbers in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, security, random

From what i know Random() is initialize to the current time. If two connections hit during the same second i should get the same two random numbers? With a large site that can be likely. Locking is bad so how should i solve it? note: the number is used for the session id.

-edit- i am stuck using a long. It feels wrong to shorten a 128bit GUID

Comment: there have been many questions on this topic on SO....

Comment: If all you have is a long, then you can't get the 128 bits of "randomness" out of a GUID anyway, due to the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: I am curious how you could be stuck using a long. If this is a large site, why can't you afford the extra 64 bits of resources? If you can't afford to use a Guid for session identifier, wait until you see what some ViewState is!

Comment: @matt-dot-net: Its not so much about being 'stuck'. Its just by design its 64bits and i dont want to change code to support 128. And there is no reason i cant use 64bits.

Comment: Guid.NewGuid is not a lot of code, and if you are using ASP.Net, the default is a 128 bit guid - why are you changing to 64 bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, why do you need to create your own session id?  Are you using [SessionIDManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.aspx) ?  I would use the Guid.NewGuid() method like what is shown in in the example [CreateSessionID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.createsessionid.aspx)
. According to the documentation for [Guid.NewGuid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx), "The chance that the value of the new Guid will be all zeros or equal to any other Guid is very low."

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using a random number from a call to `Random()`, use a [Guid.NewGuid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx).  The chance of a duplicate is very, very small...

Using a GUID for a session ID is a common solution.

Comment: Specifically, Guid.NewGuid(), (otherwise you could actually construct duplicate guids).  Guid.NewGuid() is essentially a psuedo-random number generator

Comment: would Convert.ToInt64(guid); be fine?

Comment: i did leave a comment - essentially what you said was "Don't use a random, use a random"

Comment: Yes, they are two different things entirely, exactly the point I have been trying to make to you.  One is a concept and the other is a value data type.  But, when you mention Guid.NewGuid() then you are generating a pseudo random number and then the only difference is size of the data.  Your edited answer makes more sense now. +1