# How do i securely make reset keys and login tokens?

Tags: .net, security

In the past i seen people say [use a guid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173590/secure-random-numbers-in-asp-net/3173606#3173606) and i am sure i seen it more then once.

Then in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196981/is-it-a-risk-squishing-guid-to-64bits-to-use-as-a-login-key) and searching before writing the question it appears GUID should not be used for anything related to security. So my question is, how do i make a random 64bit number as reset key or login key? I was suggested to do the below but i heard when using RNG if two cores do it at the same time it will have the same seed thus not be secure. Should i have a static function with a lock(rng){} with the code below and call that? Is there another way? How should i do this?

```
using (var rng = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    byte[] inBytes = new byte[4];
    rng.GetBytes(inBytes);
    return BitConverter.ToInt64(inBytes,0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to security is not necessarily in the key. If you generate a random key of sufficient length, and you store that key in your database with an expiration date, then your solution should be secure enough. Just generating a secure hash would not be sufficiently secure for my tastes, but if the key has to be in my database, then I can have confidence when I get one back.

Why an expiration date? Not necessarily for added security, but just because they are generally intended for immediate use. If the user doesn't use a password reset key within a day, I want to expire it and make them ask for another. The reset message went somewhere, and if it is wandering in cyberspace (maybe in someone else's mailbox) better to limit its lifetime.

What do I mean by "confidence?" Simply this: There is a high probability that the key is one that I generated. If the key is just internally consistent (secure hash), then if someone stumbles upon my method of generating the key, then they can generate a fake key. Granted, if I use a private crypto key to generate the hash, they would need to find my private key. But if they did, then my database would be exposed.

If, on the other hand, I generate a large random key and store it in my database, the only way for someone to break the system is to guess a key that is in the database. If I expire them, and invalidate them once they are used, then a sufficiently large key makes this unlikely. If you add some bad guess security, like redirecting away from the back door page after a few bad guesses, then you make it extremely hard for someone to guess a reset or back-door key. With this, I am "confident" that a successful back door attempt was authorized by me, and I can use the algorithm in my application.

We do this in a large payment-process application. We and out customers are very happy with the security provided.

Comment: ha, i thought rand om key meant a random O.M. key. Now i realize you just added a space. Ok so 1) Why an expiration date? 2) what does "then I can have confidence when I get one back" mean?

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. I have expanded my answer.

Comment: good answer. I invalidate them once it is successful. How big is 'large'? is this 1024bits? higher? i am using 64bits. Like i said i doubt anyone can guess it even if they know which RNG i use and know the time the key was reset/logs in. ATM this is 100% 'good enough' but i ask because i'd like to know when it counts. I dont know much about RNGCryptoServiceProvider, random() and i still think using the first and last half of a GUID as a 64bit number is secure. But anyways +1 for the good answer and explanation of of your technique. This key is indeed in a db and the thought of prv/pub is crazy

Comment: We use then entire GUID. Since we send them out in emails as links that the user can click on, their length isn't a big issue.